# dynamic dtype when decoding bytes from protocol buffer / tfrecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to read TFRecords files in the python interface of tensorflow. Each example in the file includes an n-dimensional tensor and its original datatype. The n-dimensional tensor is serialized to bytes before being saved. When reading the TFRecords files, I would like to decode each tensor according to its datatype. When I try this, however, I run into errors because `out_type` of `tf.io.decode_raw` does not expect a tensor. I have included an example below. How can I dynamically assign the `out_type` based on the dtype stored in the example?

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def serialize(x):
    feature = {
        "value": _bytes_feature(x.tobytes()),
        "dtype": _bytes_feature(x.dtype.name.encode('utf-8'))}

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return example.SerializeToString()

def parse(serialized):
    features = {
        "value": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
        "dtype": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)}
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized, features=features)

x = np.random.random_sample((10, 10, 10)).astype(np.float32)
serialized = serialize(x)
parsed = parse(serialized)

# This line causes the error.
tf.io.decode_raw(parsed["value"], out_type=parsed["dtype"])

# This works.
tf.io.decode_raw(parsed["value"], out_type="float32")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.io.decode_raw(parsed["value"], out_type=parsed["dtype"].numpy().decode())
```

From original out_type tensor get its value numpy=b"float32". Then decode the bytes to string which will give "float32" (or other dynamic dtype).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer would be greatly improved if you added some explanation alongside your code; perhaps explaining what specific improvements you're making to OP's code and why theirs wasn't right. This will make your answer more helpful to those who might have similar problems, and thus make it more likely for your answer to be upvoted.

Comment: I cannot use `.numpy()` because that is not serializable to the graph.